# Custom Column in Power Query Editor - Look up value in another table based on multiple criteria

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

So first of all I am new to Power Query Editor or M as it seems to be know as.

I have two tables, as below...

Job Table

- CreateDate
- PlacementEndDate
- ComputedEndDate (achieved in Power BI as
  a custom column, basically if placementenddate is null it defaults to
  createdate)

and

PlacementWeeks

- WeekStart (always a sunday)
- WeekEnd (always a saturday)

I am trying to add a custom column in Power Query editor to the job table which is as below...

```
let mydate=[ComputedEndDate] in 
Table.Max(
Table.SelectRows(
#"PlacementWeeks", each [WeekStart] >= mydate and [WeekEnd] <= mydate),
"WeekEnd")

[WeekEnd]
```

The column just returns error, for context as 'ComputedEndDate' falls back to createdate if placementenddate is null then I am trying to make sure that I can always find the closest Saturday to the ComputedEndDate column from the placementweeks table and returning this.

The placements weeks table is a big list of sundays and saturdays going on well into the future.

My question is what am I doing wrong in the M query firstly, secondly I am wondering if this is actually the best place to do this, should I be doing this as a measure or column outside of the data modelling and use DAX?

Any help would be most appreciated.

See below for image of error
[image]

**Update**

Thanks to a combination of horseyride,spinfuzer and me correcting my logic which was just plain wrong,see below for final working comlumn...

[image]

Comment: Please provide some sample data as copiable text and expected results

Comment: There is no closing ) to the List.Max in your screenshot and the )) needs to be )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
List.Max(
Table.SelectRows(
#"PlacementWeeks", (x) => x[WeekStart] >= [ComputedEndDate] and x[WeekEnd] <= [ComputedEndDate])
[WeekEnd]
)
```

This does feel like it would be slow if you had a large data set.  The x prefix refers to the columns in your PlacementWeeks table and no prefix (or _ prefix) refers to the columns in your Job Table.

Comment: In theory that looks exactly like what I want when I apply it as a custom column the column returns as error for all rows

Comment: I have added an image of the error to main description

Comment: This code cannot work. It is missing ) for the List.Max

Comment: I fixed the closing ) when using spinfuzers example see image from main description

Comment: you put it in the wrong place

Comment: whoops, sorry I was missing the closing parenthesis ).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want

```
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Maxdate",  (x)=>List.Max(Table.SelectRows(JobTable, each [CreateDate]>=x[WeekStart] and [CreateDate]<=x[WeekEnd])[ComputedEndDate]))
```

It adds a column to the PlacementWeeks table. We grab rows from JobTable where [CreateDate] on JobTable is between the [WeekStart] and [WeekEnd] dates. Then we grab the maximum of column [ComputedEndDat] from those rows

Or you can just find the closest Sunday directly

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStepNameGoesHere", "ClosestSunday", each if   List.Contains({1,2,3},Date.DayOfWeek([DateColumnNameGoesHere])) then  Date.AddDays(Date.EndOfWeek([DateColumnNameGoesHere],Day.Monday),-7) else if Date.DayOfWeek([DateColumnNameGoesHere])=0 then [DateColumnNameGoesHere]  else      Date.EndOfWeek([DateColumnNameGoesHere],Day.Monday))
```

or closest Saturday

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStepNameGoesHere", "ClosestSaturday", each if  List.Contains({0,1,2},Date.DayOfWeek([DateColumnNameGoesHere])) then  Date.AddDays(Date.EndOfWeek([DateColumnNameGoesHere],Day.Sunday),-7) else if Date.DayOfWeekDateColumnNameGoesHerethen [DateColumnNameGoesHere]  else      Date.EndOfWeekDateColumnNameGoesHere
```

[image]

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for the response much appreciated, that looks great but not quite what I need.

I need to add the column to the job table, so that it adds an extra column to the job table that is always a saturday, this is because I have a relationship that I need to add between placementweeks enddate to job 'this new column' and I need them to always be a saturday

Comment: Can I also ask, where is it that you would execute that code? If I go to add column in power editor it doesn't like that syntax

Comment: you have to manually paste it as a step in home...advanced editor....

Comment: And I'm lost what you need, so if this helps, great, otherwise Im sure Sam or David will chip in

Comment: Also lost but have an upvote anyway

Comment: I am basically needing to add a custom column to the job table that looks up the closest weekend from the placement weeks table based on the createdate field from job

Comment: So if create date was today, end date from placement weeks table would be 23/12/2023